# How to create one file and data store in php?

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
$myFile = "folder1/folder2/order.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');fwrite($fh, $Message);
    fclose($fh);
```

I am use this code.But file is not create in that particular folder

Comment: Check the permission of your directory.

Comment: Look in your server's error logs.

Comment: Slso you may not have `folder1/folder2/` so create them with [php.net/mkdir](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mkdir.php) or with console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$myFile = "folder1/folder2/order.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a'); or die("Unable to open the file");
fwrite($fh, $Message);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

If this code shows "Unable to open the file" that means there is something wrong while opening the file. This may happen if the `folder1/folder2` doesn't exist. Or may be you are not **permitted** to open a file to write on that folder. If you are in `Linux` you can change the permission of you directory like this:

```
chmod 777 folder/folder2
```